# JavaScript Prototypes and jQuery Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I am creating the following code in JavaScript (inside **file1.js**)

```
function ABC () {
    this.property01 = true;
}

ABC.prototype.doSomething = function () {

    if (this.property01 == true) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Then later in a separate file in my project (lets call it **file2.js**), I have the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var abc = new ABC();

    // Some code here

    abc.doSomething();

    // continue with code
});
```

So far, everything is correct.

Now, what I would like to do is inside the prototype definition of `doSomething()` in **file1.js**, I want to use jQuery. Something along the lines

```
function ABC () {
    this.property01 = true;
}

ABC.prototype.doSomething = function () {

    if (this.property01 == true) {

        $('#find-element'). ....   // ... Do Something
    }
}
```

But I am not sure how to do this. If I wrap the code of **file1.js** with a jQuery *document-ready* wrapper, then the line `var abc = new ABC();` inside **file2.js** will throw an error because it no longer recognizes the function definition in **file1.js**.

Can I use jQuery inside a prototype the way I explained above? How can I do that? How can I structure my files to allow for this to happen?

Comment: there's a lot of missing info here (post a MCVE), but most likely it's going to work... did you try?

Comment: Why are you waiting for the document to load before defining a class? You should make global variables.

Comment: You can keep everythig as it is, just take care, that you're not calling `doSomething` method before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine just as long as jQuery has fully loaded before `file1.js` and `file1.js` have. If you explicitly load them in the correct order, the `$` will be available globally, and the other files shouldn't have an issue recognizing that object. In fact, if you load things correctly, you shouldn't even need a document-ready setup to gain access to `$`.

```
 <script src="../jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="../file1.js"></script>
 <script src="../file2.js"></script>
```

If, for some reason, you're having conflicts with the `$` object, you could also just use the word `jQuery` to make your calls: `jQuery('#find-something')`